# CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ckeditor

so my code is:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

function TextEditor({ token }) {
  const editorRef = useRef();
  const [editorLoaded, setEditorLoaded] = useState(false);
  const { CKEditor, ClassicEditor } = editorRef.current || {};
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    editorRef.current = {
      CKEditor: require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react").CKEditor,
      ClassicEditor: require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic"),
      Paragraph: require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph"),
    };
    setEditorLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-[#F8F9FA] h-5/7 overflow-y-scroll max-w-6xl mx-auto">
      {editorLoaded ? (
        <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data=""
          config={{
            plugins: [Paragraph],
            toolbar: ["bold", "italic"],
          }}
          onReady={(editor) => {
            // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
            console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
          }}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            setData(data);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextEditor;
```

so the problem is  I only want the Paraghraph in my editor but when I run this code it returns `CKEditorError: ckEditor-duplicated-modules` I have also tried to add `.Paragraph` in front of the import for the paragraph is there something wrong with the code

**Note** next js 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best tip is use **next/script** I guess.

```
import Script from "next/script";
...
<Script ... />
```

Because you will import CKEditor in a different way "outside" NextJs libs.

**OR try this way :**

```
    const Resumos = () => {
        const editorRef = useRef()
        const [ editorLoaded, setEditorLoaded ] = useState( false )
        const { CKEditor, ClassicEditor} = editorRef.current || {}

        useEffect( () => {
            editorRef.current = {
              CKEditor: require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react' ).CKEditor, //Added .CKEditor
              ClassicEditor: require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' ),
            }
            setEditorLoaded( true )
        }, [] );
        
      const [data, setData] = useState('');

        return( 
          <>
            {editorLoaded ? <CKEditor
                editor={ ClassicEditor }
                data={data}
                onReady={ editor => {
                  // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                  console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);           
                } }
                onChange={ (event, editor ) => {
                  const data = editor.getData()
                  setData(data);
                } }
            /> : <p>Carregando...</p>}
        </>
        )
    }
```

## Editing configs ( removing editor options, etc )

```
    <CKEditor
      ...
      config={{
        removePlugins: ['Image', 'ImageCaption', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageUpload', 'MediaEmbed']
      }}
        ...
    >
    </CKEditor>
```

## Editing toolbars

```
    <CKEditor
      ...
      toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
        ...
    >
    </CKEditor>
```

React ckEditor integration reference:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html

Config reference :
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html

Try this and keep me in touch.
Hope this tip solves the problem!

Comment: The other solution works but i want to eliminate the InserImage field from the editor

Comment: Try to change options as this example:

`
 .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
      removePlugins: ['CKFinderUploadAdapter', 'CKFinder', 'EasyImage', 'Image', 'ImageCaption', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageUpload', 'MediaEmbed'],
    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
`

Comment: where do i put this

Comment: Added on answer ;)

Comment: it returns an error CKEditorError: plugincollection-required {"plugin":"ImageUpload","requiredBy":"EasyImage"}

Comment: Shahab try changing toolbars. I added on answer how to do.

Comment: also can you tell me how add font color and font size

Comment: Try to add to config  'fontSize' and 'fontColor'. For example : 

toolbar: [ 'heading', 'fontSize', 'fontColor', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],

Comment: it does not add font color